# How do you change an autoincremented columns starting value through liquibase?

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I am using MySql for my database.  I have found how to set a column's starting autoincrement value when creating a table, but I need to know how to set a new starting value for an existing column.  What does the liquibase script look like to do that?

Comment: You'll probably have to use [custom SQL](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql) for this. `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=XXX;`

Comment: yeah that's what it's looking like. thanks for the response.

Comment: Unfortunately it's DBMS specific and a pretty rare thing to do, so I could see why Liquibase doesn't really support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL syntax is pretty straightforward:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = val ;
```

(Note that this is really a table attribute, not a column attribute.  There can be only one column in a table declared to be AUTO_INCREMENT.)

This syntax isn't supported in SQL Server or Oracle; Oracle doesn't even have a concept of an "auto_increment" column, apart from a SEQUENCE object and a TRIGGER.  SQL Server calls it an IDENTITY property.  So I don't know how this statement would be represented in "liquibase" syntax, other than specifying that this statement is native MySQL syntax.

Comment: so just wrap that MySql statement in a <sql> tag in my liquibase changeset then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addAutoIncrement` (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_auto_increment.html) to change your existing AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Don't forget to specify `columnDataType` in the `addAutoIncrement`.

I used this yesterday for our project and it worked (for MySQL).